# Authenticating with PKI in Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, authentication, pki

I'm wrestling with trying to authenticate in an AngularJS application using PKI. All of the questions and examples I've seen show authentication using a login/password instead. However, I am running on an intranet, where we use PKI keys consistently. I've read the various suggestions online, but none seem to discuss my particular architecture.

The Angular side contains multiple pages/controllers, and I have no way of controlling which page the user visits first. I need the authorization information on each page.

The application is set up with a NodeJS REST service to get the user's authorizations and other information based on the user's public key (passed in thru the certs). Since the NodeJS service must contact external servers, I want to only invoke it only once, and retain an authorizedUser object (probably in rootScope?)

I've looked at creating services, providers, etc. But none seem to fit this challenge. To summarize:

- Authorization using PKI certs, not login/password
- Certs used to reach NodeJS REST service, but must only be invoked once
- Multiple Angular controllers/pages need authorization information

What would be the best approach here?

Comment: What about to, send the certificate to the server and generate a jwt token valid for each request?

Answer (score 1):

OK - I figured it out. My approach was to put the webservice call to the NodeJS backend in the module.run(), and set the $rootScope within the $http.get().success() block. The NodeJS backend gets the certs from the webservice call, and does the lookups it needs to do.

I'm not sure if that's the best approach, but it works for now.